# Determine the number of of common element locator in Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to dynamically select an element using a for loop. In order for me to determine the range, I need to know the count of the elements, how do I do this in selenium (python). Do i need to execute a javascript for this?

```
# count = how??

for i in range(1, count): #element index start at 1
        xpath = '//div[@class="form-group"]/select/option['+str(i)+']'
        if self.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath).text == driver_name:
            self.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are trying to count no of option on a select field, if that's the case, try this

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select as WebDriverSelect
s_element = WebDriverSelect(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(your_xpath_expression))
count = len(s_element.options)
```